# InterChangeAbility Between Mac-Terminal and PowerShell

Tags: windows, macos, powershell, gcc, terminal

it's grad to see you.

I have a question.

It's about InterChangeAbility between Mac-Terminal and PowerShell.

First of all, how can I run the .exe file made from Mac-Terminal in the PowerShell?

I made C++ .exe file in Mac-Terminal and I sent it to Win11 by OneDrive.
But it can't move at that.

I used gcc compiler.(command was "g++")

Thanks to you, all.
Best Regards.

Kuniaki Yui

P.S.
I would like to use both Mac and win11 for engineering.

Comment: `.exe` files are specific to the Windows platform. Generally, unless extra steps are taken, compilers will generate binaries (executables) that are specific to the host platform, so one created on macOS won't run on Windows, for instance. Generating binaries for a different platform requires [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) functionality.

Comment: Dear mklement0, thank you for your kind answer. I understood them. I would look for cross-compiler. Thank you very much. I also learned about .exe file (it's only used in terms for Windows). Really appreciate.

Comment: Since you are a C++ user, my guess is that `CMake` is your best choice for a cross-compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would use Azure instead.